# Override context. properties and functions

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

After creating my canvas, and getting `var context = can.getContext('2d')`, all my canvas work is done by setting properties or calling a method on `context.`

I have created a multi monitor screenshot tool, working great on a single monitor. However now, I am dealing with multiple monitors, so different screen top/left and scale. Sometimes (like on Windows platform with custom DPI level) I have to scale the points. Therefore I wanted to pass all setting of properties and methods through an override function so that before calling the real `context.BLAH` it will first translate the coordinates to scaled and offset by the current screen coordinates.

I can scale the context, however this really causes visual issues with anti aliasing.

Is this possible?

I tried overiding context.lineWidth and context.fillRect but I got native access errors.

I wanted to avoid wrapping it with a:

```
function lineWidth(a) {
doConvesionOnA(a)
ctx.lineWidth = a;
}
```

And then call via the function wrap each time. But if that's the only way to go Ill wrap it. I just wanted to ask please first before I create a wrap for each property and method and then replace all my `context.` calls with my wrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible with methods, but not with properties as these goes through validation and the value is simply rejected if not of a valid type, i.e. a function can not be set to replace it (and neither would it be able to update the internal settings *if* it could).

I would recommend instead to use a wrapper object. You can make it compatible with ordinary context by binding methods and wrapping properties:

```
function MyContext(ctx) {

    // Methods

    this.moveTo = ctx.moveTo.bind(ctx);
    this.lineTo = ctx.lineTo.bind(ctx);
    // etc.

    // Properties

    Object.defineProperty(this, "lineWidth", {
        get: function() {return ctx.lineWidth},
        set: function(value) {
            // do something magic with value
            ctx.lineWidth = value
        }
    });

    // etc.
}
```

If you wanted to alter values for methods:

```
this.moveTo = function(x, y) {
    // alter here
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
};
```

You can also use `apply()` which is flexible but slower than passing in actual arguments:

```
this.arc = function() {
    ctx.arc.apply(ctx, arguments)
};
```

It may be a bit tedious but leaves you in full control of what is passed through to the real context. Then simply create an instance of the object and use it as with 2D context:

```
var myCtx = new MyContext(ctx);
myCtx.lineTo(100, 100);
myCtx.lineWidth = 20;
...
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the start! I'll go this direction.

Comment: Thanks very much for that note on `apply` I didnt know it was slower. I'll make sure to not do that.

Comment: Thanks so much, its working perfectly!! https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/editor-revamp/resources/scripts/editor.js#L4423-L4544

Comment: @Noitidart great to hear! (nice project btw).

Comment: Thanks for the note on my project! :) I am trying to make an open source free version of snagit, it's firefox only right now though, if you use Firefox please check it out! :) https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nativeshot/ - the released version there doesnt have the new editor I'm working on and has some bugs :(

Comment: @Noitidart will do, I use both FF and SnagIt so I would be interested to take a closer look at this (I like the OCR capability too, something I miss in SnagIt) :)

Comment: Oh wow! You're the perfect candidate I'm targeting haha Thanks so much! :D It actually all started because some people that couldn't afford to drop cash on SnagIt needed a screenshot tool. I might not yet be able to replace SnagIt yet but I really hope to in the future, this next release (v1.8 with editor) is starting to catch up to snagit. All the while I want to keep it lightweight and fast in all ways memory etc. I will definitely keep you updated on the progress!

Comment: Hey @k3n I just released a beta please check it out if you have some time :) https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/4in0w2/beta_testers_especially_maclinux_for_screenshot/

Comment: @Noitidart thanks. I am checking it out. Seem to work fine and it gives me what I need!

Comment: Woohoo thanks so much for that comment! I really love to give back to people that help me out. Showing someone what I did with their help is one step. And if it actually comes in handy to you that is the ultimate step, very rare! Thanks! :) What operating system are you on please? :)

Comment: Hi K3n, are you Ken Saunders on ghacks and github? If you are i just wanted to say thanks! I use Firefox as a platform and for everything I do as well. If my computer is on, fx is on :)

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with @K3N's recommendation to wrap the context.

Here's some code I grabbed out of my CanvasRendingContext2D logger that shows how quickly you can started wrapping the `CanvasRendingContext2D`:

```
function LoggedContext(canvas) {
    var self = this;
    this.canvas=canvas;
    this.context=canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.imageURLs=[];
    this.fillStyles=[];
    this.logs=[];
    this.commands=[];
    this.funcs={};
    this.init(self);
}
```

In the `LoggedContext.prototype.init` method, create get/set blocks for each of the properties and mirror each of the context methods by piping all the received arguments to the "real" context using `.apply`.

```
LoggedContext.prototype.init=function(self){

    // create get/sets for properties
    var properties=['strokeStyle','lineWidth','font','globalAlpha',
        'globalCompositeOperation','shadowColor','shadowBlur',
        'shadowOffsetX','shadowOffsetY','lineCap','lineJoin',
        'miterLimit','textAlign','textBaseline'];

    for(var i=0;i<properties.length;i++){
        (function(i) {
            Object.defineProperty(self, i, {
                get: function () {
                    return this.context[i];
                },
                set: function (val) {
                    this.log(i,val,true);
                    this.context[i]=val;
                }
            })
        })(properties[i]);
    }

    // create mirror methods that pipe arguments to the real context
    var methods = ['arc','beginPath','bezierCurveTo','clearRect','clip',
      'closePath','fill','fillRect','fillText','lineTo','moveTo',
      'quadraticCurveTo','rect','restore','rotate','save','scale','setTransform',
      'stroke','strokeRect','strokeText','transform','translate','putImageData'];

    for (var i=0;i<methods.length;i++){   
        var m = methods[i];
        this[m] = (function(m){
            return function () {
                this.context[m].apply(this.context, arguments);
                this.log(m,arguments);
                return(this);
        };}(m));
    }

    // mirror methods that have return values
    var returnMethods = ['measureText','getImageData','toDataURL',
      'isPointInPath','isPointInStroke','createImageData'];

    for (var i=0;i<returnMethods.length;i++){   
        var m = returnMethods[i];
        this[m] = (function(m){
            return function () {
                return(this.context[m].apply(this.context, arguments));
        };}(m));
    }

    // In this example code ...
    // These Properties & Methods requiring special handling have 
    // been removed for brevity & clarity
    //
    //  .fillStyle
    //  .strokeStyle
    //  .drawImage
    //  .createLinearGradient
    //  .createRadialGradient
    //  .createPattern


} // end init()
```

*All property get/set and all method calls are channeled through the `LoggedContext.prototype.log` method.*

For your purposes you could either make your adjustments in the get/set blocks or conveniently make adjustments in the `.log` method because everything is piped through the `.log` method.

```
LoggedContext.prototype.log=function(command,Args,isProperty){
    var commandIndex=this.commands.indexOf(command);
    if(commandIndex<0){
        this.commands.push(command);
        commandIndex=this.commands.length-1
    }
    if(isProperty){
        this.logs.push([commandIndex,Args]);
    }else{
        this.logs.push([commandIndex,Array.prototype.slice.call(Args)]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for helping me get started with the code marke! I'll do the wrapping thing as you both recommend.

Comment: Thanks so much for this it really helped guide me a ton! https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/editor-revamp/resources/scripts/editor.js#L4423-L4544